# Trackball Tooltip Overlapping Circle with Text when `TrackballDisplayMode.groupAllPoints`

Tags: flutter, syncfusion

Widget:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

class BloodPressureChart extends StatefulWidget {
  const BloodPressureChart({super.key});

  @override
  State<BloodPressureChart> createState() => _BloodPressureChartState();
}

class _BloodPressureChartState extends State<BloodPressureChart> {
  List<BloodPressureMeasurement>? bloodPressureMeasurements;

  @override
  void initState() {
    bloodPressureMeasurements = [
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 14, 0, 0),
        systolic: 120,
        diastolic: 80,
        pulse: 70,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 16, 1, 0),
        systolic: 130,
        diastolic: 85,
        pulse: 75,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 2, 0),
        systolic: 118,
        diastolic: 78,
        pulse: 72,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 3, 0),
        systolic: 140,
        diastolic: 90,
        pulse: 80,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 4, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 5, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 6, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 7, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 8, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 9, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 10, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 11, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 12, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 13, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 14, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 15, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 16, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 17, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 18, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 19, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 20, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 21, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 22, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 23, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
      BloodPressureMeasurement(
        recordedAt: DateTime(2023, 9, 18, 24, 0),
        systolic: 125,
        diastolic: 82,
        pulse: 68,
      ),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SfCartesianChart(
      series: _getStackedLineSeries(),
      title: ChartTitle(text: 'Tensiune'),
      legend: const Legend(
        isVisible: true,
        overflowMode: LegendItemOverflowMode.wrap,
        position: LegendPosition.bottom,
      ),
      primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(
        majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0),
        isVisible: false,
        dateFormat: DateFormat('y.M.d k:mm'),
      ),
      primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
        majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(color: Colors.transparent),
      ),
      trackballBehavior: TrackballBehavior(
        enable: true,
        activationMode: ActivationMode.singleTap,
        tooltipSettings: const InteractiveTooltip(
          format: 'series.name:point.y mmol/L',
          
        ),
        tooltipDisplayMode: TrackballDisplayMode.groupAllPoints,
      ),
    );
  }

  List<LineSeries<BloodPressureMeasurement, DateTime>> _getStackedLineSeries() {
    return [
      LineSeries<BloodPressureMeasurement, DateTime>(
          dataSource: bloodPressureMeasurements!,
          xValueMapper: (measurement, _) => measurement.recordedAt,
          yValueMapper: (measurement, _) => measurement.diastolic,
          name: 'Diastolic',
          animationDuration: 2500,
          color: Colors.lightBlue),
      LineSeries<BloodPressureMeasurement, DateTime>(
          dataSource: bloodPressureMeasurements!,
          xValueMapper: (measurement, _) => measurement.recordedAt,
          yValueMapper: (measurement, _) => measurement.systolic,
          name: 'Sistolic',
          animationDuration: 2500,
          color: Colors.blue.shade900),
      LineSeries<BloodPressureMeasurement, DateTime>(
          dataSource: bloodPressureMeasurements!,
          xValueMapper: (measurement, _) => measurement.recordedAt,
          yValueMapper: (measurement, _) => measurement.pulse,
          name: 'Puls',
          animationDuration: 2500,
          color: Colors.red),
    ];
  }
}

class BloodPressureMeasurement {
  BloodPressureMeasurement({
    required this.recordedAt,
    required this.systolic,
    required this.diastolic,
    required this.pulse,
  });

  final DateTime recordedAt;
  final int systolic;
  final int diastolic;
  final int pulse;
}

enum TimeMeasureUnit { day, week, month, last6months, year, max }
```

Where it is called:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:medical_app/widgets/blood_pressure_mesurement_chart_widget.dart';
import 'package:medical_app/widgets/blood_sugar_measurement_chart_widget.dart';

import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

class MeasurementsChartsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MeasurementsChartsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MeasurementsChartsScreenState createState() =>
      _MeasurementsChartsScreenState();
}

class _MeasurementsChartsScreenState extends State<MeasurementsChartsScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        title: const Text('Masuratori'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications_none_outlined),
          ),
        ],
        // bottom:
      ),
      body: const SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            BloodPressureChart(),
            SizedBox(height: 12),
            BloodSugarChart(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am using the Syncfusion library to draw line charts.
I can't seem to figure out why the colored circles keep overlapping with my text. Am I missing something?
This happens only when I use `TrackballDisplayMode.groupAllPoints` property.
It gets even weirder when I try to move it to the over side, closer to the right.

[image]